# What are the most important steps in constructing neural netwoks for object detection? (NOT CLASSIFICATION)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, convolution, object-detection, conv-neural-network

I have been working with machine learning for a few months now. I have used caffe and darknet and will now start with theano. There are 2 major tasks in machine learning: 1. Detection and 2. Classification. Although I understand how most classification networks are made or designed, I cannot get a clear picture of what are the basic steps involved in constructing a neural net to detect images. In classification, we use appropriate max pooling, relu and conv layers to get better results and fine tune the network. What are the important things that need to be kept in mind whilst making a neural network for object detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, what you call 'detection' is usually solved by regression task (so, 'neural networks for regression'). For example, you want to recognize a tip of a nose on the picture (and nothing else). You mark up the the training images so that you have:

X (the input) - just image of size, say, 256x256 pixels, greyscale
Y (the output) - pair of numbers which show X,Y coordinate of the location of the tip of the nose on this image.

Then you built a DNN to solve regression task on this problem. Same principles are applied for this NN as for classification. You could use max-pooling layers, convolution layers, ReLUs whatever you want. You just need to keep in mind that your output layer should be capable of outputting the numbers which are in the required range and that's it.

Good tutorial on solving this task with ANNs is [here](http://danielnouri.org/notes/2014/12/17/using-convolutional-neural-nets-to-detect-facial-keypoints-tutorial/)

P.S. You want to detect *region* where object is located (like enclose it in a colored box in image)? No problem, one solution would be to solve regression task for times to locate top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right corners of the object. Or use sliding windows if you like.